# What do I have to do on my end once I get approved for Spanish family reunification visa?

Tags: spain

I am from the United States and my husband has applied for me to come live with him in Spain. He is not a Spanish citizen so we have applied through the family reunification visa. I have not found anywhere online someone in this same situation.

Has anyone been through this or have knowledge on what I am to do before I leave for Spain?

Comment: Where did you apply? Who approved the visa?

Comment: Has a visa been issued to you?

Comment: The application process begins in Spain. That is where my husband has applied for me. The visa has not been approved yet but our lawyer does not know what we are to do once it has been, because she has never had someone from the U.S. apply through family reunification.

Comment: If the lawyer who's handling the application doesn't know "what happens next," then the lawyer isn't competent to do this work and should be replaced.

Answer (score 1):

If it's approved, you should apply inmediately for a TIE (Spanish foreign card). This is a mandatory step and you are going to need it anyway.

Ensure you are "empadronado" in the same home as your spouse. Otherwise you might find issues at renewal.

And that's should be it for now. Your TIE should be enough to prove your right to work to an employer. Once your residence is going to expire, you should be applying for switching to a permanent residence card.